# why is the parameter Xd_co_f parameter added in my href URL

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

i'm trying to redirect to a URL from a ajax success function, but the parameter xd_co_f is appended to the query of the URL when redirected. How do I remove the unwanted parameter?

I tried to hardcode the URL to anchor tag i did not face this issue only when redirecting from ajax success function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example before posting question.

Comment: Are you getting same result if you go incognito?

Comment: Same is happening on our prod site.

Comment: This Xd_co_f parameter seems to be added by something else instead of asp.net itself. Could you show what code you use to make the redirection?

Comment: I would bet this is a tracking mechanism added by some tracking solution - either as a part of the web server (as some module), or as a library in the code, or (less likely) coming from vendor ensuring network access (something of a Cloudflare-ish or Anti-DDoS type). E.g., Oracle Infinity platform mentions "wt.co_f" parameter (https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/marketing/infinity-develop/docs/parameters/cookie_detection.htm) - in the same way, some other platform might employ "Xd_co_f". Double-check all the cookies you see in request/response, and maybe you'll find out your culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether your site uses Oracle infinity analytics.

**xd_co_f** is appended to your URL if you use Oracle infinity for analytics.

[image]